# Recycler View reset form fields On Scroll

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView. Data comes from a server. A list item view contains:

```
one TextView
one EditText
one Button
```

I have 10 list items. When I click the button data will send to the server, and after successful submission the button visibility is set to `View.INVISIBLE`. The problem is that When submit the button (data will send and button visibility set to INvisble) and scroll down and up the submitted list remains the same i.e. visibility changes to visible.

Bind the view holder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder1 holder, final int position) {
    final Ardlist_item listitem = listitems.get(position);

    holder.textitemname.setText(listitem.getItemname());
    holder.liftqty.setText(listitem.getQty());

    holder.rcqty.setText(listitem.getQty());

    holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holder.b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.rcqty.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(context, "clicled" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Getting the position

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listitems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView liftqty;

    public Button b1;
    public EditText rcqty;
    public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        textitemname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        liftqty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lifted_qty);

        b1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.receive_btn);
        rcqty = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.received_qty);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes sure, i add details in answer  fields